# Wiring a 3-way switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I have a hallway light that was originally wired to 2 switches, with 3 wires at each switch. But a previous owner replaced one of the switches with a 2-way dimmer switch and capped the third wire. Now the light will only turn on if both switches are in one particular configuration, which is annoying.

I have bought a new 3-way dimmer that I want to use to restore the 2-switch functionality (with dimming at one end), but I don't know how to match up the wires.

What I have is:

1. One one end, an original 3-way switch (2 black wires and 1 red wire)
2. On the other end, a 2-way switch wired to 2 black wires with red capped off
3. A new Lutron dimmer switch with black, red, red/white wires ([instructions](https://ledt8bulb.com/pdf/lutron-dvcl-153p-install-guide.pdf))

What I want to know is how to wire the new switch to the three existing wires. And if trial/error is involved, if there is any danger of damaging anything.

Original 3-way switch wires:
[image: Original 3-way switch]

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the backs of all boxes involved please?

Comment: Do you have a multi meter?

Comment: first we kneed to know which switch is connected to the breaker and which is connected to the lamp.  the new switch needs to go at the breaker end.

Comment: Include a pic of the other side of the switch shown above. AIUI, the travelers are the two wires connected to matching color screws, but one of the electricians will confirm that for you.

Comment: The other traveler will be in the same cable as the known traveler (the red).